# Rebooting Halted Unless Manually Power Button Pressed

Tags: 22.04, reboot, headless

I had Ubuntu 20 installed in my Dell Precision 7920 Tower. When I was upgrading it to Ubuntu 22, I got disconnected on the way. Hence the upgrade was halted in the middle. Somehow I managed to get it running though. I did some steps including manually uninstalling conflicting packages. Now I don't have a GUI, only a CLI. Everything seems to be normally working.

But now, when the power is disconnected and connected again, it automatically starts, but I cannot connect over SSH and also no signal is coming to the physically connected monitor. I have to manually push the power button to turn it off and press it again to start the server. The behavior is the same when doing `sudo reboot`.

Is there a way to fix this instead of reinstalling Ubuntu? Is there a specific package that I can try reinstalling? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the list of packages that were installed before the power loss. Sometimes recovery is easy, sometimes impossible. Run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt full-upgrade`. Carefully note and resolve all error messages.